# Проблема с добавлением URL в Django

Tags: python, django

Я создал новый проект и добавил приложение 'hello'.Затем в файле views добавил функцию index.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
    def index(request):
        return HttpResponse('Hello, world!')
```

В том же приложении создал файл urls.py и добавил туда эту функцию следую инструкциям из лекции.

```
  from django.urls import path
  from . import views
    urlpatterns = [
        path("", views.index, name='index')
    ]
```

Затем добавил этот url в основной файл urls.py

```
        from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', include('hello.urls'))
]
```

После запуска выдает ошибку 404: The empty path didn’t match any of these.

Comment: очень полезный ответ. спасибо.

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста структуру приложения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не указано перенаправление на основную страничку!

Django видит это так: пользователь перешел по ссылке http://127.0.0.1:8000/ я (django) смотрю urls.py основной файл и вижу что не зада основная страница поэтому выдаю 404.

Задано только http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ или http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Когда вы создали urls.py (в hello), то маршрут начинается c http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/(здесь ваше пустое значение) для того чтобы вывести это как основную страницу вам надо в основном urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('hello.urls')) #поставить здесь пустое значение
]
```

Тогда django поймет, то что вы его перенаправляете в другой urls.py (hello) где и стоит ваше пустой значение.

Если говорить проше, то маршрут выглядит так

```
path('hello/', include('hello.urls')) --> path("", views.index, name='index')
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ + пустое значение

Итог http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/

```
path('', include('hello.urls')) --> path("", views.index, name='index')
```

Если вы сделаете так, то маршрут будет выглядит так

http://127.0.0.1:8000/ + пустое значение + пустое значение

Итог http://127.0.0.1:8000/